# access multi layer list in spring mvc controller

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

**The Case:** I've an Company Object. 
It has a list of Department Objects, and each Department has a list of Employee Objects.
 
In JSP, I have a grid list(designed in HTML that binds a input to an employee object (deep down 2 hierarchies. That is Company->Department->Employee). And each object of the employee is bind to a label .

```
< td class="fmtxt">< form:label path="company[${pIndex.index}].Department[${ioIndex.index}].Employee.emp_cd"/>${io.Employee.emp_cd }< /td>
```

As you can see:
Department[0].employeeList --> employee 1
Department[1].employeeList --> employee 2

The binding is good. After form is submitted, in the controller, I can loop over  department List and find all departments created but the employee list is empty(length is zero).

**The Details:** To give you the details of my work:
A Company  class has list of Department. A Department class has a list of Employees. Employee has first and last name and other details.

```
public class Company{
  private long id;
  private String Compname;
  private List<Department> DepartmentList;   
// *default constructor and all getters and setters*
}

public class Department{
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private List<Employee> employeeList; 
  //*default constructor and all getters and setters*
}

public class Employee{
  private long id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private long Amount;
  //*default contructor and all getters and setters*
}
```

So I have 1 JSP form: which has a layout 
Company A
Department A
Employee A
amount textbox

```
< form:form name='fs' action="department.htm"  method='POST' modelAttribute="Company">
       < table id="comp" >
              < c:forEach items="${Company.DepartmentList}" var="p" varStatus="pIndex">
                   < tr>< td>< form:input path=”DepartmentList[${pIndex.index}].name"  /> < /td> < /tr><br>
                     < tr>< td><br>< table>
        < c:forEach items="${p.employeeList}" var="po" varStatus="poIndex">
               < tr>< td>< form:hidden path="DepartmentList[${pIndex.index}].employeeList[${poIndex.index}].id"/>
<form:input path="DepartmentList[${pIndex.index}].employeeList[${poIndex.index}].firstName"/>
< /td>
< td>< form:input path="DepartmentList[${pIndex.index}].employeeList[${poIndex.index}].Amount"/>< /td>
               < /tr><br>   
                   < /c:forEach>   
                  < /table>
    < /c:forEach>
    < /table>
</form>
```

The Employee Controller (the one that's getting null employeelist)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String product_post(@ModelAttribute Company company, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) 
{
      System.out.println("CONTROLLER");
      List<Department> Departments = company.getDepartmentList();
      for(Department dept: Departments){
        System.out.println("dept name::: " + dept.getName()); 
        List<Employee> employeeList = dept.getEmployeeList();
        System.out.println(dept.getEmployeeList ).size()) 
// prints zero ; employee list become empty after it is returned to the controller

        for(Employee emp: employeeList)
        {
          System.out.println("Employee::"+ emp.getFirstName());
        }
      }

    return "employee"; // jsp page 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the list of employee from manager and its not an empty list? I think opensessioninview filter would solve your problem.

Comment: yes i am getting the list of the employee when first time the page loads. I am able to design the page .  it is after I submit the page this list become blank and size returns is zero.